# incorrect form representation in the tutorial from the web2py book

Tags: forms, web2py

I am trying to run the example from this tutorial:
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Say-my-name

as said in the book i have edit this 3 files in my "sand" application:

1)default.py

```
def first():
    return dict()

def second():
    return dict()
```

2)first.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>What is your name?</h1>
<form action="second">
  <input name="visitor_name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

3)second.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Hello {{=request.vars.visitor_name}}</h1>
```

but when i go to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sand/default/first` - i have the word "First" instead of web form and buttons: (design request response session db tables db stats)

not enough reputation to paste a screenshot :(

what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your first.html view is inside the /views/default folder and not directly inside /views. web2py will look for a /views/default/first.html view, and if it doesn't exist, it will instead use the /views/generic.html view (by default, it will only use the generic view on localhost) -- sounds like that is what's happening.

Comment: No, i check it, the path is /views/default/first.html

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. In your case, the generic.html view is being used, so something isn't set up right. Is it possible you have compiled the application prior to making the first.html view? If you compile an application, you must uncompile and recompile if you make any changes.